# Extract two strings from a line of text with Ansible

Tags: python, list, filter, ansible

I have this list from a shell output.

```
- 192.168.20.76:3260,1054 iqn.1992-08.com.netapp:sn.f4bc76f43e2611e883e200a098d2174a:vs.6
- 192.168.21.126:3260,1056 iqn.1992-08.com.netapp:sn.f4bc76f43e2611e883e200a098d2174a:vs.6
- 192.168.21.125:3260,1055 iqn.1992-08.com.netapp:sn.f4bc76f43e2611e883e200a098d2174a:vs.6
- 192.168.20.75:3260,1053 iqn.1992-08.com.netapp:sn.f4bc76f43e2611e883e200a098d2174a:vs.6
- 192.168.22.20:3260,1052 iqn.1992-08.com.netapp:sn.f4bc76f43e2611e883e200a098d2174a:vs.6
- 192.168.22.19:3260,1051 iqn.1992-08.com.netapp:sn.f4bc76f43e2611e883e200a098d2174a:vs.6
```

I want to get both the IP and the iqn.xxxxx from the list when the IP is in the same vlan as the host.

I am able to create a list of the correct IP's but can't figure out how to also get the corresponding iqn.

Code:

```
  - hosts: test_server
    gather_facts: yes 
    tasks: 
      - name:
        set_facts:
          iscsi_vlan: '192.168.20.64/28'
      - name: iscsiadm discovery
        command: /usr/sbin/iscsiadm iscsiadm --mode discovery --type sendtargets --portal {{ storage_fqdn }}
        register: iscsiadm_out
      - name: facts
        set_fact:
          target_list: "{{ target_list + item | regex_findall('(^\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3})') | ipaddr( iscsi_vlan ) }}"
        loop: "{{ iscsiadm_out.stdout_lines }}"
      - name: target_list
        debug: 
          var: target_list
```

target_list contains this. It matches the correct subnet using the ip_addr function.

```
ok: [test-server] => 
  target_list:
  - 192.168.20.76
  - 192.168.20.75
```

Basically I end up with trying to search in a list with the contents of another list.

- I've tried with_subelements but it requires a string and a list
- I've tried to figure out how I can extract both the correct IP and the iqn from iscsiadm_out in one go with regex, but can't.
- I've contemplated turning iscsiadm_out into a json object and then use json_query, but I don't know how to do that.

How can I either use this list to extract the iqn from iscsiadm_out or maybe in a totally different way?

I understand I can use commands like grep and awk in the command module, but I don't like that option.

In my testing I have searched around here and elswhere on the Internet for hours.
I'm a novice at Ansible and a total noob at python and jinja2, but I tried to investigate those paths too to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other ways to acheive the same result but you can build-up on the below concepts. I'm simply extracting your expected info at once in a dict list (each dict containing an ip/iqn pair) and looping over it to filter out the expected elements.

The demo playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Extract IP and IQN
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    # This is what you get from your command
    iscsiadm:
      stdout_lines:
        - 192.168.20.76:3260,1054 iqn.1992-08.com.netapp:sn.f4bc76f43e2611e883e200a098d2174a:vs.6
        - 192.168.21.126:3260,1056 iqn.1992-08.com.netapp:sn.f4bc76f43e2611e883e200a098d2174a:vs.6
        - 192.168.21.125:3260,1055 iqn.1992-08.com.netapp:sn.f4bc76f43e2611e883e200a098d2174a:vs.6
        - 192.168.20.75:3260,1053 iqn.1992-08.com.netapp:sn.f4bc76f43e2611e883e200a098d2174a:vs.6
        - 192.168.22.20:3260,1052 iqn.1992-08.com.netapp:sn.f4bc76f43e2611e883e200a098d2174a:vs.6
        - 192.168.22.19:3260,1051 iqn.1992-08.com.netapp:sn.f4bc76f43e2611e883e200a098d2174a:vs.6

    iscsi_vlan: '192.168.20.64/28'

  tasks:
    - name: "Create a list of {ip: x, iqn: y} dicts from the command result"
      vars:
        current_entry:
          - ip: >-
              {{ item | regex_replace('(^(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}).*$', '\g<1>') }}
            iqn: >-
              {{ item | regex_replace('^.* (iqn\.\d*-\d*.com.netapp).*$', '\g<1>') }}
      set_fact:
        ipqn_list: "{{ ipqn_list | default([]) + current_entry }}"
      loop: "{{ iscsiadm.stdout_lines }}"

    - name: Debug element when ip is in our subnet (change to whatever is relevant)
      debug:
        msg: "IP {{ item.ip }} with IQN {{ item.iqn }} is in our subnet"
      loop: "{{ ipqn_list }}"
      when: item.ip | ipaddr(iscsi_vlan)
```

gives the result:

```
PLAY [Extract IP and IQN] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Create a list of {ip: x, iqn: y} dicts from the command result] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=192.168.20.76:3260,1054 iqn.1992-08.com.netapp:sn.f4bc76f43e2611e883e200a098d2174a:vs.6)
ok: [localhost] => (item=192.168.21.126:3260,1056 iqn.1992-08.com.netapp:sn.f4bc76f43e2611e883e200a098d2174a:vs.6)
ok: [localhost] => (item=192.168.21.125:3260,1055 iqn.1992-08.com.netapp:sn.f4bc76f43e2611e883e200a098d2174a:vs.6)
ok: [localhost] => (item=192.168.20.75:3260,1053 iqn.1992-08.com.netapp:sn.f4bc76f43e2611e883e200a098d2174a:vs.6)
ok: [localhost] => (item=192.168.22.20:3260,1052 iqn.1992-08.com.netapp:sn.f4bc76f43e2611e883e200a098d2174a:vs.6)
ok: [localhost] => (item=192.168.22.19:3260,1051 iqn.1992-08.com.netapp:sn.f4bc76f43e2611e883e200a098d2174a:vs.6)

TASK [Debug element when ip is in our subnet (change to whatever is relevant)] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'ip': '192.168.20.76', 'iqn': 'iqn.1992-08.com.netapp'}) => {
    "msg": "IP 192.168.20.76 with IQN iqn.1992-08.com.netapp is in our subnet"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'ip': '192.168.21.126', 'iqn': 'iqn.1992-08.com.netapp'}) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'ip': '192.168.21.125', 'iqn': 'iqn.1992-08.com.netapp'}) 
ok: [localhost] => (item={'ip': '192.168.20.75', 'iqn': 'iqn.1992-08.com.netapp'}) => {
    "msg": "IP 192.168.20.75 with IQN iqn.1992-08.com.netapp is in our subnet"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'ip': '192.168.22.20', 'iqn': 'iqn.1992-08.com.netapp'}) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'ip': '192.168.22.19', 'iqn': 'iqn.1992-08.com.netapp'}) 

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and kind help! This works just the way I wanted! I moved the closing parenthesis in the iqn regex to grab to the end of the line as I need all of it.
I did upvote but since I am new here I don't have enough reputation to make it publicly visible.

Comment: You need some more reputation to get your upvote (should be ok shortly), but you can still accept (green tick) either answer if one of them fixes your issue. This will let others know there is a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the items of the list and create a dictionary, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        ipqn_dict: "{{ ipqn_dict|default({})|
                       combine({index: {'ip': ip,
                                        'port': port,
                                        'iqn': iqn,
                                        'code': code,
                                        'vs': vs}}) }}"
      loop: "{{ iscsiadm_out.stdout_lines }}"
      vars:
        a: "{{ item.split(',') }}"
        ip: "{{ a.0.split(':').0 }}"
        port: "{{ a.0.split(':').1 }}"
        b: "{{ a.1.split(' ') }}"
        index: "{{ b.0 }}"
        iqn: "{{ b.1.split(':').0 }}"
        code: "{{ b.1.split(':').1 }}"
        vs: "{{ b.1.split(':').2 }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  ipqn_dict:
    '1051':
      code: sn.f4bc76f43e2611e883e200a098d2174a
      ip: 192.168.22.19
      iqn: iqn.1992-08.com.netapp
      port: '3260'
      vs: vs.6
    '1052':
      code: sn.f4bc76f43e2611e883e200a098d2174a
      ip: 192.168.22.20
      iqn: iqn.1992-08.com.netapp
      port: '3260'
      vs: vs.6
    '1053':
      code: sn.f4bc76f43e2611e883e200a098d2174a
      ip: 192.168.20.75
      iqn: iqn.1992-08.com.netapp
      port: '3260'
      vs: vs.6
    '1054':
      code: sn.f4bc76f43e2611e883e200a098d2174a
      ip: 192.168.20.76
      iqn: iqn.1992-08.com.netapp
      port: '3260'
      vs: vs.6
    '1055':
      code: sn.f4bc76f43e2611e883e200a098d2174a
      ip: 192.168.21.125
      iqn: iqn.1992-08.com.netapp
      port: '3260'
      vs: vs.6
    '1056':
      code: sn.f4bc76f43e2611e883e200a098d2174a
      ip: 192.168.21.126
      iqn: iqn.1992-08.com.netapp
      port: '3260'
      vs: vs.6
```

This should simplify the selection of required data, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ipqn_dict|json_query('*.[ip,iqn]') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  - - 192.168.20.76
    - iqn.1992-08.com.netapp
  - - 192.168.21.126
    - iqn.1992-08.com.netapp
  - - 192.168.21.125
    - iqn.1992-08.com.netapp
  - - 192.168.20.75
    - iqn.1992-08.com.netapp
  - - 192.168.22.20
    - iqn.1992-08.com.netapp
  - - 192.168.22.19
    - iqn.1992-08.com.netapp
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind help and time! This is a great way of extracting text and sorting it into a dict. I will need this later on for other use cases. 
I did upvote but since I am new here I don't have enough reputation to make it publicly visible.